# Display a Snackbar in a fragment after deleting an item from the database?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-snackbar, snackbar, android-data-usage

I am looking for a way to have a Snackbox pop up at the bottom of the display when the user deletes an item from the database using the `caseR.id.delete:`. Below I have attached code from the fragment. If you need more of my code from different areas, please let me know.

```
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class MainActivityListFragment extends ListFragment {
    private ArrayList<Note> notes;
    private NoteAdapter noteAdapter;
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        /*
        String[] values = new String[] {"Android", "iPhone", "Windows", "WebOS", "Android", "iPhone", "Windows", "WebOS" };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        */

        NotesDbAdapter dbAdapter = new NotesDbAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext());
        dbAdapter.open();
        notes = dbAdapter.getAllNotes();
        dbAdapter.close();

        noteAdapter = new NoteAdapter(getActivity(), notes);

        setListAdapter(noteAdapter);

        getListView().setDivider(null);
        getListView().setDividerHeight(0);

        registerForContextMenu(getListView());



    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        launchNoteDetailActivity(MainActivity.FragmentToLaunch.VIEW, position);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        MenuInflater menuInflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.long_press_menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){

        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        int rowPosition = info.position;
        Note note = (Note) getListAdapter().getItem(rowPosition);

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.edit:
                launchNoteDetailActivity(MainActivity.FragmentToLaunch.EDIT, rowPosition);
                Log.d("menu clicks", "we pressed edit");
                return true;
            case R.id.delete:
                NotesDbAdapter dbAdapter = new NotesDbAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext());
                dbAdapter.open();
                dbAdapter.deleteNote(note.getId());

                notes.clear();
                notes.addAll(dbAdapter.getAllNotes());
                noteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                dbAdapter.close();
        }

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);

    }

    private void launchNoteDetailActivity(MainActivity.FragmentToLaunch ftl, int position){

        Note note = (Note) getListAdapter().getItem(position);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NoteDetailActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.NOTE_TITLE_EXTRA, note.getTitle());
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.NOTE_MESSAGE_EXTRA, note.getMessage());
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.NOTE_CATEGORY_EXTRA, note.getCategory());
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.NOTE_DATE_EXTRA, note.getDate());
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.NOTE_ID_EXTRA, note.getId());

        switch(ftl){
            case VIEW:
                intent.putExtra(MainActivity.NOTE_FRAGMENT_TO_LOAD_EXTRA, MainActivity.FragmentToLaunch.VIEW);
                break;
            case EDIT:
                intent.putExtra(MainActivity.NOTE_FRAGMENT_TO_LOAD_EXTRA, MainActivity.FragmentToLaunch.EDIT);
        }

        startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have coordinate layout present in your layout?

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle add latest design library.

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:X.X.X' // where X.X.X version
```

And then, in your fragment do:

```
Snackbar  
    .make(view, "Item deleted",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
    .show();
```

The parameter `view` could be the fragment's root layout. You just need it's reference.

For more information see http://www.materialdoc.com/snackbar/

Answer (score 0):

1. Add design Lib

   ```
      Compile 'com.android.support:design:X.X.X'
   ```
2. Code:

   ```
      case R.id.delete:
           NotesDbAdapter dbAdapter = new NotesDbAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext());
           dbAdapter.open();
           dbAdapter.deleteNote(note.getId());

           notes.clear();
           notes.addAll(dbAdapter.getAllNotes());
           noteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

           dbAdapter.close();

           // Show SNACK Bar
           mRoot = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.mainrl);

           Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(mRoot , "Item Deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
           snackbar.show();
   ```

here **mRoot** is your main root layout of your fragment.